# Markov chain - probability - stochastic process

Tags: probability, statistics, markov-chains

I got stuck here:

The probability that it will rain today is that it did not rain in the previous two days is $0.3$, but if it rained in one of the last two days then the probability of rain today is $0.6$.

$W(n)$ is a random variable that receives the value $1$ if in the $n\ge1$ day it rained, and the value $0$, if it's not.

I need to explain why the series $(W(n))_{n\ge 0}$ is not a Markov chain, but when they define $X_n=(W_n,W_{n-1})$, so $(W(n))_{n\ge 0}$ it is a Markov chain!

Answer (score 0):

Markov chains only depend on the previous state.  But W_n depends on W_(n-1) and W_(n-2).  What does X_n depend on?

Comment: X_n=W_(n-1) and W_(n-2).

I need to explain why the series (W(n))n>=0 is not Markov chain

Comment: any help? any hint?

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the last two days states fix the current day's distribution. Knowing what happend 3 day or 4 days or n days before does not add any information. Hence Xn is a marcovian.